# Find all paths from a vertex until there are no more direct successors

Tags: scala, graph

I am working on an app that simulates a workflow into a form of a graph. I am using Scala-Graph to achieve this and I want to find out all the possible direct edge paths until there are no more direct successors.

For example, for this graph:

```
val z = Graph(1~>2, 2~>3, 2~>4, 3~>4, 5~>4)
```

I would like to find out all the possible paths from **vertex 1** to vertices with no more direct connections. So the output of the logic should be similar to

```
1~>2~>3~>4
2~>4
```

Main questions:

1. Is there a native API provided by scala-graph to achieve this?
2. Should I write a customer traverse method?

In regards to question 2, I have written an initial version of the code to achieve it but it's always returning an empty value ;( I would appreciate some feedback on this too

```
def getAllPaths(g: z.NodeT, paths: List[Any]): Unit = {
  val directs = g.diSuccessors.toList
  if (directs.length == 0) {
    paths
  } else {
    getAllPaths(directs(0), paths :+ directs(0))
  }
}

val accum = List[Any]()

println(getAllPaths(z.get(1), accum)) // nothing
```

So the idea is, by passing in a starting point to the method getAllPaths, it will traverse according to `diSuccessors` and stops when its length is 0. Ideal output for the example graph z is

```
[
  [1~2, 2~3, 3~4]
  [2~4]
]
```

Why does the custom method return an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

So I've written this to achieve it

```
// Example graph 1
val z = Graph(1~>2, 2~>3, 2~>4, 3~>4, 5~>4)
// Example graph 2
val z1 = Graph(1~>2, 2~>3, 2~>4, 3~>4, 4~>6, 6~>7, 5~>4)

def getAllPaths(g: z1.NodeT, paths: List[z1.NodeT]): List[Any] = {
  val directs = g.diSuccessors.toList

      if (directs.length == 0) {
          // No more direct successor left, return the array itself
        paths
      } else if (directs.length == 1) {
        // Node with single direction, simply returns itself
        if (paths.length == 0) {
          // appends g itself and its direct successor for the first iteration
          getAllPaths(directs(0), paths :+ g :+ directs(0))
        } else {
          // Appends only the direct successor
          getAllPaths(directs(0), paths :+ directs(0))
        }
      } else {
        directs.map(d => {
          getAllPaths(d, paths :+ d)
        })
      }
    }
val accum = List[z1.NodeT]()

println(getAllPaths(z1.get(1), accum))

// Results in: List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7), List(1, 2, 4, 6, 7))
```

Leaving it here just in case if anyone is interested in solving the same problem!

*Also please help me write it more elegantly* ;) .. I'm still a beginner in Scala

Follow up questions:

- How do I reference the type NodeT without going through a variable like above example, which is accessing it via `z1.NodeT`?